# "Automatic is not a valid StreamPoints specification"

Tags: plotting, warning-messages

If I run

```
StreamPlot[{a, b}, {a, 0, 10}, {b, 0, a}]
```

the kernel hangs, and I have to restart it. I also get the error message

> StreamPlot::strmpts: Automatic is not a valid StreamPoints specification.

If I try to manually specify `StreamPoints`, the kernel still hangs, and the error message changes: e.g., with `StreamPoints -> 10`, I get

> StreamPlot::strmpts: 10 is not a valid StreamPoints specification.

(For the record, I'm using 10.4.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit)).

What's going on here? What does this message mean, and how can I fix it?

Comment: same issue in v9 (windows 10/64bit)

Comment: Same error with v12 (macOS 10.14.6)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No idea why it doesn't work as in `Plot3D[ a b , {a, 0, 10}, {b, 0, a}]`...

Try `RegionFunction`

```
StreamPlot[{a, b}, {a, 0, 10}, {b, 0, 10},RegionFunction -> Function[{a, b}, b < a]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Which version are you using? Mine is 10.4. Can you confirm that the same error happens for v>10.4?

Comment: The same error in v11.01!

Answer (score 3):

`StreamPlot` is not designed to work with such domain specs.  It ought to give a better message though.  Actually it doesn't seem to validate the domain before sending it to the internal routines.  (Probably, it used a standard plot validation, but the internal routines assume the limits are numeric, i.e., that it's a rectangle.)

```
tr = Trace[
   StreamPlot[{a, b}, {a, 0, 10}, {b, 0, a}],
   _Visualization`VectorFields`VectorFieldsDump`StreamPointsParse,
   TraceInternal -> True];
```

> StreamPlot::strmpts: Automatic is not a valid StreamPoints specification.

```
Cases[
 Flatten@tr, 
 HoldForm[parse_Visualization`VectorFields`VectorFieldsDump`StreamPointsParse] :>
  parse]
```

> StreamPlot::strmpts: Automatic is not a valid StreamPoints specification.

```
(*  {None}  *)
```

One can inspect `StreamPointsParse` and its subroutines with `` GeneralUtilities`PrintDefinitions ``, if one's curious.  It's fairly short code and easy to follow.